# Codeigniter/REST Showing Incorrect Results

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to create a login script using CodeIgniter and the REST Controller (https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restclient) however; I keep getting a null response from my model

this is my model function

```
public function login($data)
    {
        $checkEmail = $this->db->get_where('users', array('email' => $data['email']));

        $emailRow = $checkEmail->row();

        if(isset($emailRow)) {

            if (password_verify($data['password'], $emailRow->password)) {

                return $emailRow->id;

            } else {

                return false;

            }

        } else {

            return false;

        }
    }
```

this is my controller

```
public function login_post()
    {
        $this->load->model('User_model');

        $data = $this->_post_args;

        if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {

        //does some unnecessary stuff thats pointless showing

            $this->set_response([
                'status' => FALSE,
                'error' => $error
            ], REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);

        } else {

            $login = $this->User_model->login($data);

            if($login === TRUE) {

                $user = $this->User_model->getUser($login);

                $this->set_response([
                    'status' => TRUE,
                    'user' => $user
                ], REST_Controller::HTTP_ACCEPTED);

            } else {

                $this->set_response([
                    'status' => FALSE,
                    'error' => 'Nope'
                ], REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);

            }

        }
    }
```

everytime i run this, i get the 'nope' error message and `$login` is returning as null if i var_dump it? anybody got any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you are checking:

```
if($login === TRUE) {
```

Unfortunately, for your controller, the model will **NEVER** return `TRUE` so your code falls into your `else{}` block every single time.

Your model only returns `FALSE` or the value of `$emailRow->id`

As an immediate fix, you can try:

```
if($login !== FALSE) {
```

Comment: what a silly mistake on my behalf! thank you so much - silly mistakes i always miss. guess thats what happens when you are starting at code for hours on end

Comment: You're welcome. At some point "days on end" will be your new norm and you will reminisce about the times when you only spent "hours on end". The best thing you could do is get in the habit of practicing good debugging methodologies (<- this is a subject for another day) regardless of how tired or fresh you feel. Good luck!